# Windows constantly restarting or BSOD

Tags: windows-10, bsod, crash

Windows constantly restarting or BSOD
Hello,

I have a desktop computer that repeatedly either restarts without a BSOD or even with one. The errors seem to be all over the place but I'm sure they mean something in their totality. I've run sfc /scannow which returned no issues. I tried "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" which didn't resolve any issues. At that point I tried to do a clean install which was incredibly difficult as the install kept crashing. I've also disabled all onboard hardware on my motherboard.

So far the only time it seems remotely stable is when I am booted in command prompt safe mode. I've downloaded as many latest drivers for my hardware I can but some won't install in safe mode. My bios is the latest non beta version. Here is the hardware:

Ryzen 3600

32 GB GSkill ram

Sapphire Radeon RX 580

Two M.2 ssd drives, one Mushkin and the other Samsung

Corsair AX860 power supply

I disconnected my other two drives.

This is a series of dumps I've recorded so far. I can't tell what the relation is between these and it's not particularly been stable ever but now it's so bad it's unusable. I've also verified the cpu is not overheating.

https://pastebin.com/AJdX8pZL

ATTEMPTED_EXECUTE_OF_NOEXECUTE_MEMORY

APC_INDEX_MISMATCH

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION

POOL_CORRUPTION_IN_FILE_AREA

Comment: Usually frequent restarts are caused by a faulty or not powerful enough PSU

Comment: I did the math and it seems as though 860 watts should be sufficient. The BSODs don't even always BSOD properly. Sometimes there is no error message, has visual artifacts, or only turns partially blue. It appears far more stable in safemode than under a regular boot.

Comment: Additional information, I just managed to keep it up long enough to run Basemark to stress test the GPU and about halfway through the screen turned black. Using an infrared thermometer and just my hand nothing seems to have over heated. After reboot it says DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

Comment: Maybe a faulty driver,that's why it was working in safe mode, disable all unnecessary one and run your pc for a while.

Comment: Looks possible? The only BasemarkGPU test that does this is the Vulkan test. OpenGL and DirectX has no issues. I just reseated every single card and installed all of the official AMD drivers. Every other test ran fine in all levels except the Vulkan tests.

Comment: I've had more time to deal with this and since I am experiencing weird issues in both linux and Windows I feel it may be a deeper issue. Perhaps hardware. I just am unsure what to replace first.